# Why is the Strunk and White badge not shown in the review-badge-progress-mouseover-thingy?

Tags: feature-request, review, badge-progress

As you can see here

[image: Progress bars]

the top progress bar shows the progress towards the next badge of that category (in my case the "Reviewer" badge") but the third bar always shows the "Copy Editor" badge instead of (in my case) the "Strunk and White" badge.

Is this intentional? Otherwise, take this as a feature request or a bug report, whichever term you like more.

Comment: Would be cool if there would be a small vertical line indicating the Strunk and White position in the Copy Editor line, like it is in the progress bar on the left side of the tabs...

Comment: Would be even cooler if they replaced that useless Civic Duty indicator with something more useful... Maybe Legendary or Sportsmanship?

Comment: @animuson Yeah, but on the other hand, those are not really related to reviewing. It would be nice to have progress bars for all badges though.

Comment: And also probably the "**Civic Duty**" badge for votes.

Comment: Has there been any movement on this issue?